# To get the common letters in two words without repetition

Tags: python

Write the function `getCommonLetters(word1, word2)` that takes in two words as arguments and returns a new string that contains letters found in both string. Ignore repeated letters and sort the result in alphabetical order.

Examples

```
>>> getCommonLetters('apple','google')
'el'
>>> getCommonLetters('microsoft','apple')
''
>>> getCommonLetters('microsoft','google')
'o'
```

My solution is as follows:

```
def getCommonLetters(word1, word2):

    for letter in word1:
       if letter in word2:
            #return letter
            return ''.join(sorted(letter))
    return ''
```

Comment: i am getting some incorrect outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)

```
>>> ''.join(set('apple').intersection(set('google')))
'el'
```

The function can be defined as

```
def getCommonLetters(a, b):
    return ''.join(sorted(set(a).intersection(set(b))))
```

Example

```
>>> def getCommonLetters(a, b):
...         return ''.join(sorted(set(a).intersection(set(b))))
... 
>>> getCommonLetters('google','apple')
'el'
```

Comment: i dont want the answer in the form of a list.

Comment: @hermankaur It is in the form of a string. Please do execute the code

Comment: Glad to be of help. Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `set()` and set intersection to find the common elements of two sets -

```
def getCommonLetters(word1, word2):
    return ''.join(sorted(set(word1) & set(word2)))
```

& is for `set intersection` .

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def getCommonLetters(word1, word2):
...     return ''.join(sorted(set(word1) & set(word2)))
...
>>> getCommonLetters('apple','google')
'el'
>>> getCommonLetters('microsoft','apple')
''
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want correction to your solution, then the problem is that you return the first common letter that you find. You have to continue searching for common letters and combine them into a result:

```
def getCommonLetters(word1, word2):
   res = ""

   for letter in word1:
      if letter in word2:
         if letter not in res: # skip if we already found it
             # don't return yet, but rather accumulate the letters
             res = res + letter

   return res
```

The solutions suggesting using `set` can be faster, especially if you are checking long words.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ''.join(sorted(set([letter for letter in word1 if letter in word2])))
```

Explanation:

1. `[letter for letter in word1 if letter in word2]`: Iterate over the letters in `word1` and check if the current letter is contained by `word2`. If so add it to the list of common letters (with duplicates).
2. `set( 1. )`: Remove duplicates by creating a set out of the list of common letters.
3. `sorted( 2. )`: Sort the common letters (alphabetically).
4. `''.join( 3. )`: Create a string, joining the common letters by whitespaces (without duplicates).

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you could add some explanation as to why it works.